# how to select sepecific email domain from email column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have CUST_TBL with one of the column are EMAIL and USER_ID.

I have many records in CUST_TBL, but I only want to show the record which have specific email domain (like @gmail.com) and user with USER_ID = 'SYSADMIN1'.

I have tried this query

```
select substr(email,INSTR(email,'@gmail.com')) 
from  corp_usr 
where user_id = 'SYSADMIN1';
```

But it only shows the email column (I want all column but only with those filter) and still shows the email that's not @gmail.com

What is the correct query for this?

Comment: So you want all columns with a condition that email contains `@gmail.com`, but you also want to show records where email doesn't contain `@gmail.com`. I don't follow your logic.

Comment: I want to select data from all column that ONLY contain `@gmail.com` in email column. Because I also have many records that's not using gmail domain like `@yahoo.com` -  Kamil G.

Comment: @sagi has already given you the solution - and you don't mean ONLY contain, but contain.

Comment: `select * from corp_usr where user_id='SYSADMIN1' and email like '%@gmail.com'` In "like" clause `%` mean any symbols.

Comment: You have **two** criteria for restricting records in the result set therefore you need **two**  filters in the`where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `INSTR()` in the `WHERE` clause :

```
select * from  corp_usr 
where user_id = 'SYSADMIN1'
  AND INSTR(email,'@gmail.com') > 0;
```

Comment: The query is correct, the explanation is not... `INSTR()` returns the **position** in the input string (`email` in this case) at which the search string (`@gmail.com` in this case) is found, or it returns 0 if the search string is not found anywhere in the input string. If you are interested in more than one occurrence, that can be passed in as a parameter, but it is not what the return value means. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm

Comment: @mathguy Oopsy, the sad thing is that I knew that :P deleted the comment.